# Can we use LUIS and Text Analytics API together

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, text-analytics-api

i need to develop a chat bot on azure for user interaction i have used LUIS and now want the bot to perform analyze the chat and suggest user the necessary changes. So, should i use text analytic API for it and does LUIS and text analytic API can be used together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text analytics can [determine sentiments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-sentiment-analysis), [extract key phrases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-keyword-extraction) and [detect the language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-language-detection) used. If you want to find the intent of the user or extract entities from a text, you can use [LUIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/Home).

For "The hotel is the worst ever" a sentiment analysis can tell that the sentiment is negative. For the same sentence key phrase extraction extracts the key words/phrases: "hotel, worst", without any interpretation of the meaning or context.

For "Turn on the yellow light", LUIS can be trained to extract intent (Operate Light) and entities (Action: turn on, Object: Yellow Light) with a meaning and a context.

Text Analytics and LUIS expose separate APIs that just takes texts as input, so they can be used independently of each other. They have no integrations built in between them, so that's up to the consumer to implement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I had a question again actually i have a set of input being entered by the user and need to process that data to generate a para phrase form the information. So, text analytics help me out there.